# bug: OAuth (using SO's account) form, hidden button

Tags: bug, status-completed, oauth2

When I tried to [login on trac.nginx.org](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/chrome/site/auth.html) using my Stack Exchange account I got such the form after logining in Stack Overflow:
[image: shown form]

It was strange thus I inspect the page with DevTools (in my case Chromium's DevTools) and found the following:

[image: form under dev tools]

I clicked on the highlighted space and the permission became approved.

Comment: also reported on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345611/approve-button-on-oauth-authorization-dialog-is-invisible

Comment: @rene , thanks! I checked that I gave more information and now post the problem solution from the point of view on the html page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the CSS of the "s-btn__primary" class.

If you change it from original...

```
.s-btn__primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: var(--blue-500);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

to...

```
.s-btn__primary {
    border-color: var(--red-500);
    background-color: var(--blue-500);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

(took the color from the ".s-btn__outlined" )

OR to...

```
.s-btn__primary {
    border-color: var(--red-500);
    background-color: var(--blue-500);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

and the ".s-btn__outlined" class to the "Accept" button.

Comment: Thanks for digging in! You're right that `.s-btn__primary` is misbehaving there, but the core issue seems to be that we're missing our [design library](https://stackoverflow.design) on the page. Once we have that included, both the approve and reject buttons should have correct styling - that white button with a border looks intentionally styled, but it isn't. :) I'll get this fixed up tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I was right and we were, in fact, missing the design library reference.

The fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!